# Header Div Disappears in Large Resolution - Media Query

Tags: html, media-queries

I am trying to put in a different image for each resolution. It worked for normal screen and smartphones, however I cannot get it to show up for the large resolution screens. Here are the relevant sections of code:

CSS:

```
/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1800px) {
html { 
  background: #000000 url(images/blackmagic.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body { 
  background-color:transparent;
  font-size: 100%;
  color:#000000;
}

h1 {
  color:#000000;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-family: 'Sancreek', Impact, sans-serif;
  font-size:2.5em;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Pathway Gothic One', Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size:1.875em;
  color:#000000;
}

a:link {
  color:#000000;
}

a:hover {
  color:#9b0505;
}

p {
  color:#000000;
  font-family: 'Monda', Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size:0.875em;
  text-align:justify;
}

#container {
    position:relative;
    width: 2200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 0;
}

#social {
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 450px;
    z-index: 0;
}

#header {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
}

#headerm {
    display:none;
    position:relative;
}

#headerl {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
    margin-top:-500px;
    margin-left:200px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="outer">
        <div id="border" class="outer">
        <div id="header" class="inner">
            <img src="/images/header.png" id="headerimage" />
        </div>
        <div id="headerl" class="inner">
            <img src="/images/headerlg.png" id="headerimage" />
        </div>
        <div id="headerm" class="inner">
            <img src="/images/headerm.jpg" id="headerimage" />
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no HTML ? Also posting a quick fiddle would make this so much easier to debug!

Comment: I would update it with the HTML, however I've totally messed it up at this point... You can view it here, if viewing the source would be easier? http://theshavebarber.com/about.php Thank you for taking the time to look at it, Jason! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I actually just figured it out!

Because I was hiding the DIV for regular Desktop/Laptop Resolution and not defining the max-width for that value in its Media Query, it was also hiding it in the Large Resolution Media Query.

Simple fix of defining a max-width value for Standard Res.

Thanks! :)